# Как изменить стиль input[type="radio"]?

Tags: html, css

Как мне поменять стиль радиокнопок, что бы они выглядели как чебоксы?
Нужна кроссбраузерность. Нашла в интернете такой код:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    -webkit-appearance:checkbox; /*chrome,safari,opera*/
    -moz-appearance:checkbox; /*firebox*/
    -ms-appearance:checkbox; /*not currently supported*/
}
```

Но не работает в IE и опере.

На основании нишеизложенного

```js
(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").parent("label").css(" background-position","0 -21px");
});
```

```css
div.boolean br{display:none;}
div.boolean>label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
label:before{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: url('http://www.dis-ag.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/images/checkbox-sprite.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fields boolean">
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="UF_PRICE_LIST">да</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="UF_PRICE_LIST" checked="">нет</label>
</div>
```

Говорю, html код нельзя менять.

Comment: Для чего вам обманывать пользователя и выдавать радиокнопки за чекбоксы?

Comment: Было бы странно, если бы в IE заработало, учитывая комментарий ` /*not currently supported*/`.

Придётся вам всё-таки делать чекбоксы и навешивать JS'ом на них обработчики чтобы поведение было аналогично радиокнопкам.

Comment: Так не получится, так как я работаю в Битриксе, а там есть радиокнопки - в качестве полей к регистрации...

Comment: там наверняка можно указать тип переключателей, какие нужно использовать

Comment: только радиокнопки.

Comment: Обернуть текст в span и кастомизировать через селектор соседнего элемента
https://habrahabr.ru/post/144104/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например через псевдоэлементы + фоновую картинку:

```css
input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: url('http://www.dis-ag.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/images/checkbox-sprite.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  background-position: 0 -21px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="ie" name="browser" value="ie">
<label for="ie">Internet Explorer</label>
<input type="radio" id="opera" name="browser" value="opera">
<label for="opera">Opera</label>
<input type="radio" id="firefox" name="browser" value="firefox">
<label for="firefox">Firefox</label>
```

### UPD

```js
$(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").parent("label").addClass('active');
    $("input[type=radio]").on('change', function(e){
       $(this).closest('.fields').find('label').removeClass('active');
       $(this).closest('label').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
div.boolean br{
  display:none;
}
div.boolean > label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
label:before{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: url('http://www.dis-ag.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/images/checkbox-sprite.png'); /* скопировать себе на сервер */
  background-size: 100%;
}
label.active:before {
  background-position: 0 -21px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields boolean">
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="UF_PRICE_LIST">да</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="UF_PRICE_LIST" checked="">нет</label>
</div>
```

Comment: СПасибо, но это не то...

Comment: html нельзя изменять 
      html нельзя изменять
         <div class="fields boolean">
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="UF_PRICE_LIST">да</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="UF_PRICE_LIST" checked="">нет</label>
    </div>

Comment: div.boolean br{display:none;}
div.boolean>label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
label:before{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: url('http://www.dis-ag.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/images/checkbox-sprite.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}

Comment: @RRR Тогда вам только `js` в помощь

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
      if($("input[type=radio]").attr("checked") == 'checked') { 
              $("input[type=radio]").parent("label").css(" background-position","0 -21px");
       }
 });

но не получается...

Comment: @RRR Потому что вы чушь написали. Учите мат часть, ваш код из комментария как минимум вот так надо написать `$("input[type=radio]:checked").parent("label").css(" background-position","0 -21px");`

Comment: @koryoff не работает так...

Comment: @RRR так я и не сказал, что будет работать. Я лишь написал что ваш пример кода надо писать так, а правильная ли логика, этого я не знаю. Напишите подробности в ваш вопрос с примерами HTML, телепатией не страдаем

Comment: @koryoff , написала код в вопросе. если можете, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @RRR обновил ответ

Comment: @koryoff, огромное спасибо-)

Comment: @RRR если ответ вас устраивает, слева пожно нажать кнопку "Принять"